# ¿Como debo manejar mi base de datos Sqlite en android cuando tengo diferentes modulos y cada modulo tiene una base de datos diferente?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, sqlite, android-sqlite

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación la cual se extendió a diversos módulos y los dividí en diversos proyectos pero todo deben de comunicarse entre si, tengo la duda de como manejar la parte de base de datos realizar solo una base de datos o hacer una base de datos en cada proyecto y otra duda como puedo consultar la base de datos que se encuentra en otro proyecto estando en un proyecto externo.

Comment: no te recomendaría usar una base de datos global puesto que si alguna vez quieres haces testing creas una dependencia muy dificil de reemplazar. Tal vez lo ideal sea una base de datos para cada módulo.

Comment: Has pensado en desarrollar una base de datos online? usando Django o Firebase por ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que implementar un `proveedor de contenidos` en cada proyecto. De este modo los distintos proyectos podrán acceder a la información que tu decidas. Aquí la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).